# how to use one input and one output parameter in sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
create procedure spGetEmployeByDepartmentIdCount
 @DepartmentIdType int ,
 @DepartmentIdCount int output
 as
 Begin
        select count(id)
        from tblemploye1 
        where @DepartmentIdType = id    
 End

 Declare @DepartmentIdCount int
 Declare @id int 
 set @id = 1
 Execute spGetEmployeByDepartmentIdCount @id, @DepartmentIdCount output
 print @DepartmentIdCount
```

Comment: use function and it will return value

Comment: so what's the issue?

Comment: It can work, any problem?

Answer (score 1):

Your stored procedure returns only SELECT data
Since you did not assign any value to output parameter, it is NULL

You can change your stored procedure code as follows using ALTER statement

```
select
    @DepartmentIdCount = count(id)
from tblemploye1 
where
    id = @DepartmentIdType
```

Now the output parameter is assigned with the count of employees in selected department
I hope it helps